# Solving for ß for a defective repeated eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Given
\begin{equation}
x' = 
\begin{bmatrix} 4&-3\\3&-2 \end{bmatrix}x
\end{equation}
What is the general solution x?

When I solve the system for the eigenvalues, its the repeated root 1; there is only one eigenvalue \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix} so the eigenvalues are defective. I am told to find the general solution with the equation x = (ß+vt)$e^{λt}$ by first solving for ß (ß is a vector, v is the eigenvector); I get ß = v(A-tλ-1)$(λ-A)^{-1}$; however, in this case det$(λ-A)$ = 0, meaning I can't take the inverse of (λ-A) - what am I doing wrong and how do I get the general solution?

Comment: you want $e^{At}$   where $A$  is your 2 by 2 matrix of coefficients.  So, you construct a square matrix $P$   such that $P^{-1} A P = J$   is in Jordan form. We have $A = P J P^{-1},$   so that $e^{At}  = P e^{Jt} P^{-1}.$  Meanwhile, since $J = I + N$  where $N$ is nilpotent  and $IN = NI,$ it is straightforward to write $e^{Jt}.$